# Redirect to a new domain based on GET parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I already used 301 redirect many times, but this time I'm facing a new problem. I have an old website on Joomla and all the pages on the website are loaded by the same `index.php` file. Example :

```
URL of a page           : http://domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=4&Itemid=54
URL of a different page : http://domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=1&Itemid=55
```

How can I redirect each of these pages to other pages?

By example, I'd like that the page `http://domain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=4&Itemid=54` redirect to `http://newdomain.com/location/`

I need to make a 301 redirect based on GET parameters but I can't figure how.

Your help would be very appreciated !

**If possible to do this in the `htaccess` file?**

Comment: What is the changing parameter in the get where you decide to change on a specific page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a simple switch

```
switch($_GET['id']){
    case 1:   $myPage = "http://newdomain.com/location/"; break;
    case 4:   $myPage = "http://othernewdomain.com/location/"; break;
    default:  $myPage = "http://google.com"; break;
}
header("Location: {$myPage}");
```

of course you could easy add more parameters and switch them... like

```
if($_GET['id'] == 1 && $_GET['item'] == 55 ){
    $goto = 1;
}
switch($goto){ ... }
```

htaccess would be some like

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=4&Itemid=54 http://www.domain.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters that are sent through a `GET` are received as a structure like this:

```
array(n):
    name_1 = 'value1',
    name_2 = 'value2',
    ...
    name_n = 'valueN',
```

And you can access them through the `$_GET` variable, where every key equals to the name of the parameter, e.g. to access the value bound to the parameter with the name `'foo'`, you can:

```php
$bar = $_GET['foo'];
```

On your PHP script. So you can just make a simple flow controller, or a *switch* that effectively detects the parameters sent through the `GET` and redirects to the URL you're looking for:

```php
final class Redirect {

    public static function toUrl($url, $parameters = array(), $statusCode = 303) {
        header('Location: ' . $url . http_build_query($parameters), true, $statusCode);
    }

}

$parameter = $_GET['key'];

switch ($parameter) {
    case '<the specific parameter>':
        Redirect::toUrl('http://example.com/');
        break;
    case '<other case>':
        ...
}
```

The `$parameters` argument is optional and you can use it to send some other data to the new URL via `GET` too, and you can also control the status code sent via the optional `$statusCode` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rules like this your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=section&id=4&Itemid=54$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://newdomain.com/location/? [L,NC,R=302]
```

**Make sure these rules are placed before any other rules.**

Answer (score 0):

The string after the `?` in the URL is called the query string.  In PHP, it's contained in the QUERY_STRING environment variable.  So, you can do what you want to do using `if` statements in your index.php script to test the contents of the query string, like so:

```
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="option=com_content&view=section&id=4&Itemid=54") { header("Location: http://newdomain.com/location/"); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using htaccess I believe you can do that.

This should work :

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```